# How to calculate active s-boxes from branch number?

Tags: aes, matrix-multiplication, mds

If [MDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDS_matrix) in AES has branch number 5 (so 5 active s-boxes in 2 rounds), wouldn't that mean 4 rounds of AES has $5*2=10$ active s-boxes?

AES [paper](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf) says it has 25 ($5^2$?) active s-boxes in 4 rounds.

How to calculate minimal active s-boxes from branch number for any given number of rounds?

**Edit:** J.D. noted that you can't calculate the minimum number of active s-boxes from the branch number of MixColumns, because MixColumns isn't the only operation. So let's assume cipher has full state MDS like [SHARK](https://securewww.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/publications/article-55.pdf) and [Khazad](http://www.larc.usp.br/~pbarreto/KhazadPage.html).

Comment: Which paper are you referring to?

Comment: http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf (page 31)

Comment: You can't just calculate the minimum number of active s-boxes from the branch number of MixColumn, because MixColumn isn't the only operation - there is also ShiftRow.  See Theorem 2 on page 37 of the paper you linked for the proof of 25 s-boxes over 4 rounds.  This proof can be trivially expanded to $4n$ rounds for any natural number $n$.

Comment: @J.D. What about ciphers which use only MDS?

Comment: For a cipher like Khazad, the branch number of the MDS gives us an easy to compute lower bound on the minimum number of active s-boxes - for $2n$ rounds ($n=1,2,3$...) and branch number $B$, the minimum number of active s-boxes is $nB$.  The true minimum may be larger than this lower bound, but it cannot be smaller.

Comment: @J.D. So eight round Khazad has lower bound of $n/2*B = 8/2*9 = 36$ minimum number of active s-boxes?

Comment: @LightBit - yes, an 8 round characteristic involves at minimum 36 active s-boxes.  That said, a differential attack on Khazad would generally proceed by stripping off a round or two at the beginning and/or end, so the relevant number of rounds would be 6 (27 active s-boxes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Khazad has an $8\times 8$ MDS matrix $A$ used as the diffusion layer. The augmented matrix $[I|A]$ generates a $[n,k,d]=[16,8,9]$ MDS code over $GF(2^8).$ The implications are:

1. The minimum number of active Sboxes, i.e., the minimum branch number across 2 rounds is $9,$ the minimum weight of the MDS code.
2. MDS codes have a fully known weight distribution, so the full branch number distribution is also known, assuming a uniform input distribution into the Sboxes.

See [here](https://wiki.cse.buffalo.edu/cse545/content/mds-codes) for the weight distribution. Briefly,
$A_i$ denotes number of codewords of weight $i$, thus also the number of occurrences of branch number $i.$ In this case
$A_0=1,$ and $A_i=0,$ for $1\leq i \leq d-1.$ The other nonzero weights are
$$
A_i= \binom{n}{i} \sum_{j=0}^{i-d} (-1)^{j}\binom{i}{j} \left( q^{i+1-d-j}-1\right),
$$
for $d\leq i \leq n.$

Here $q=2^8, d=9.$

Comment: @LightBit does this answer your question?