# How is Twofish flattening the result of Reed-Solomon MDS matrix multiplication into a 32-bit result?

Tags: block-cipher, twofish, mds

I have trouble understanding how Reed-Solomon coding can produce same number of output bits than the input was.

Twofish uses this technique. I've read the paper, but still can't quite understand how the flattening works. In my understanding, RS should add redundant bits, and the output must be larger than the input. What am I missing?

In addition, how is the MDS matrix constructed from RS coding? It seems that it was constructed using clever heuristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In crypto diffusion layer design the MDS matrix is usually used in the following form:

$$ X_{n+1}=M X_n,$$

where the actual codewords are $(X_n | X_{n+1}).$ So it's a rate $1/2$ MDS code. It need not be Reed Solomon, and optimisations with respect to speed and other considerations are made. This is done in Twofish as well.

In particular $X_n$ is made up of the 4 words that are the outputs of sboxes $(S_0,S_1,S_2,S_3)$ and $X_{n+1}$ is the result of multiplying this vector with the MDS matrix $M$.

See the answer to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35823/how-to-calculate-active-s-boxes-from-branch--number) as well.

Comment: Would it be possible to illustrate this with an example? I'm still not quite seeing it.